# Adjective question

Tags: adjectives

Somewhat confused here. When you write out dumbass (please excuse my French) showing possession, is it written dumbass'? I know my punctuation isn't correct, but I need to know if this correct. Thank you for your help.  --Ella

Comment: By the way, this does not appear to be an adjective question. It is a question about nouns and possessives.

Answer (score 3):

Most style guides would have you add the possessive to it so that it becomes "dumbass's". For a word like "Charles", you can get away with just an apostrophe, as in "Charles' book". But this doesn't work with "dumbass". Just read the following phrase aloud and see if it sounds okay: "dumbass' book". It sounds much better as "dumbass's book".

Comment: The second one does sound much better.  Thanx for your help! -Ella